# Printing a given tuple out of an array erlang

Tags: arrays, printing, erlang, tuples

I am having some minor trouble with erlang, namely that I want to print out a given part of an array, however, I do not appear to be able to do so easily.

Here is the array I am trying to print using `array:get(X, Array)`.

```
[{carrier, [{e,10}, {f,10}, {g,10}, {h,10}, {i,10}]}, 
{battleship, [{a,1}, {a,2}, {a,3}, {a,4}]}, 
{cruiser, [{e,3}, {e,4}, {e,5}]}, 
{destroyer, [{f,4},{g,4}, {h,4}]}, 
{patrol_boat, [{j,7},{j,8}]}]
```

I am able to print out the entire array however, I am unable to get just a single tuple out of it.

Ideally I would be able to do `element(1, array:get(0, Array)).` with the return of `carrier`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your construct is a list, not an array. An [Erlang array](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/array.html) is something entirely different. You need to look at the [lists module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html) instead.

To get the first element, you can use pattern matching. Here's an example shell session:

```
1> List = [{carrier, [{e,10}, {f,10}, {g,10}, {h,10}, {i,10}]}, 
           {battleship, [{a,1}, {a,2}, {a,3}, {a,4}]}, 
           {cruiser, [{e,3}, {e,4}, {e,5}]}, 
           {destroyer, [{f,4},{g,4}, {h,4}]}, 
           {patrol_boat, [{j,7},{j,8}]}].
[{carrier,[{e,10},{f,10},{g,10},{h,10},{i,10}]},
 {battleship,[{a,1},{a,2},{a,3},{a,4}]},
 {cruiser,[{e,3},{e,4},{e,5}]},
 {destroyer,[{f,4},{g,4},{h,4}]},
 {patrol_boat,[{j,7},{j,8}]}]
2> [{ShipType, _}|_] = List.
[{carrier,[{e,10},{f,10},{g,10},{h,10},{i,10}]},
 {battleship,[{a,1},{a,2},{a,3},{a,4}]},
 {cruiser,[{e,3},{e,4},{e,5}]},
 {destroyer,[{f,4},{g,4},{h,4}]},
 {patrol_boat,[{j,7},{j,8}]}]
3> ShipType.
carrier
```

As you can see, `ShipType` will be set to `carrier` from this match.

To get other elements of the list, you can use [`lists:nth/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#nth-2). For example, to get the entire 3rd element:

```
4> Third = lists:nth(3, List).
{cruiser,[{e,3},{e,4},{e,5}]}
```

For more info about Erlang lists, take a look at any Erlang book or [any of these resources](http://spawnedshelter.com/#learning-erlang).